# Why does my text suddenly get whitespace when applying a style?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is my flutter code:

```
class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          LandingPageForm(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LandingPageForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LandingPageFormState createState() {
    return LandingPageFormState();
  }
}

final headerStyle = TextStyle();

class LandingPageFormState extends State<LandingPageForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    'Hey there!',
                    style: headerStyle,
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

If I remove the headerStyle from the fitted textbox, the padding above disappears which is how I want it. As soon as I add a style though this whitespace appears and I have no idea what is causing it.

What is going on?

Comment: What whitespace? Could you please add a screenshot of the mentioned issue?

Comment: uh oh. works fine in dart pad, this might be a device issue. I am working on samsung galaxy s7

Answer (score 0):

Closing this - it seems there is a persistent caching issue with styles on my device. Closing and reopening the app fixed the issue.